# Multiple virtual monitors for Mac guest and Mac host

Tags: mac, virtualization

I have a mac with one display. I need to simulate a mac with multiple displays. Attaching more physical displays is not an option. It looks like VMWare, Virtualbox, and Parallels cannot do this. Is there any way to simulate two displays without buying another monitor?

Comment: Does your display have multiple inputs? You might be able to connect multiple inputs to it from the same machine. As those displays probable won't be usable in a meaningful manner I'm not sure this is going to get you anywhere. As for Virtual Box if you check the [Settings](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#settings-display) there is actually a setting to have multiple, virtual displays.

Comment: I have an iMac so I can't do that. Virtual box lacks mac guest tools so its virtual monitor support doesn't work.